# How to handle the change of the previous object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently making a nav bar.
I create an array storing the info of the tabs in the nav bar.

```
            tabs: [
                { name: 'All',id: "dash.courses.all", to: 'all', current: false },
                { name: 'Self-paced Learning',id: "dash.courses.oneToOneClasses", to: 'selfPacedLearningComp', current: false },
                { name: '30 Days Challenge',id: "dash.courses.selfPacedLearningComp", to: 'thirtyDaysChallenge', current: false },
                { name: 'Group Classes',id: "dash.courses.groupClasses", to: 'groupClasses', current: false },
                { name: '1-to-1 Classes',to: "dash.courses.thirtyDaysChallenge", to: 'oneToOneClasses', current: false },
            ]
```

When a new route is clicked it updates the newly clicked tab to allow the current property to be true.

How would you change the previous nav item to false. As currently they all change to true one by one as they are clicked.

I think if I store a value as previous

```
      setCurrent(tab)
      { 
          
          let newArr = this.tabs.map(obj => {
          if (obj.id === tab) {
            return {...obj, current: true};
          }

          return obj;
        })
        this.tabs = newArr
        console.log(newArr)
      }
    },
```

This is what i've got atm, it has to go around 3 routes ahead till the one before vanishes...

```
<script>
export default {
    components: {
    },
    data()
    {
        return {
            prevTab: null,
            tabs: [
                { name: 'All',id: "dash.courses.all", to: 'all', current: false },
                { name: 'Self-paced Learning',id: "dash.courses.oneToOneClasses", to: 'selfPacedLearningComp', current: false },
                { name: '30 Days Challenge',id: "dash.courses.selfPacedLearningComp", to: 'thirtyDaysChallenge', current: false },
                { name: 'Group Classes',id: "dash.courses.groupClasses", to: 'groupClasses', current: false },
                { name: '1-to-1 Classes',to: "dash.courses.thirtyDaysChallenge", to: 'oneToOneClasses', current: false },
            ]
        }
    },
    methods: {
      setCurrent(tab)
      { 
          this.prevTab = this.$route.name
          let newArr = this.tabs.map(obj => {
          if (obj.id === tab) {
            return {...obj, current: true};
          }
          if(obj.id === this.prevTab) {
            return {...obj, current: false}
          }

          return obj;
        })
        console.log('previous ',this.prevTab)
        console.log('route name', this.$route.name)
        this.tabs = newArr
      }
    },
    mounted()
    {
      this.prevTab = this.$route.name
      const newArr = this.tabs.map(obj => {
        if (obj.id === this.$route.name) {
          return {...obj, current: true};
        }

        return obj;
      });
      this.tabs = newArr
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for 2 tabs or more to be current? If it's not then it doesn't make sense to keep `current` in each object, could be a separate value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a watcher on the route name

```js
watch: {
    "$route.name": {
      handler(routeName) {
        this.tabs.forEach((tab) => (tab.current = routeName === tab.name));
      },
      // force eager callback execution
      immediate: true,
    },
  }
```

Usually you can just use the watcher `routeName` value above to run whatever side effect you want but if tracking `current` on each tab is really necessary the above code will get the job done.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I also just see that I am not very smart... if you see the tabs array... then you look at tabs.id and then tabs.to the names do not match... I've been clicking the button and it takes me wrong place everytime... I guess thats why it hasn't been working for the last 2 hours hah.

Comment: I've run into a bug where I have another navigation component for other page. This watcher still watches the routes being changed there. Giving me some problems. Works well if there is only one navigation bar.